# python 2.7 absolute links from webpage

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code that I need to get absolute links from rather than relative links.
I believe I need to use `urlparse` and `urljoin` somewhere in here, but I'm just not sure where to use that.
The .csv from this code is also giving me rows like this: `"/about.html"` which is obviously not an link to another web page.

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import re
r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(r'(^http|.html)')}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
web_links_df = pd.DataFrame(links)
web_links_df.columns = ['web_link']
web_links_df['web_link'] = web_links_df['web_link'].apply(lambda x: 
    x.rstrip('/'))
url_tail = web_links_df['web_link'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
web_links = pd.DataFrame(web_links_df['web_link'].unique())
web_links.columns = ['web_link']
print web_links.head()
web_links.to_csv("D:/MLCV/web_links_1.csv")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have spent hours going through other examples on Stack but I am just not getting the correct results.